# Mybatis three-level mapping, mapping entity classes do not match

Tags: mybatis

```
 <resultMap id="treeNodeResultMap" type="...TeachplanDto">
        <id     column="one_id"        property="id" />
        <result column="one_pname"      property="pname" />
        <result column="one_parentid"     property="parentid" />
        <result column="one_grade"  property="grade" />
        <result column="one_mediaType"   property="mediaType" />
        <result column="one_stratTime"   property="startTime" />
        <result column="one_endTime"   property="endTime" />
        <result column="one_orderby"   property="orderby" />
        <result column="one_courseId"   property="courseId" />
        <result column="one_coursePubId"   property="coursePubId" />
        <collection property="teachPlanTreeNodes" ofType="...TeachplanDto">
            <id     column="two_id"        property="id" />
            <result column="two_pname"      property="pname" />
            <result column="two_parentid"     property="parentid" />
            <result column="two_grade"  property="grade" />
            <result column="two_mediaType"   property="mediaType" />
            <result column="two_stratTime"   property="startTime" />
            <result column="two_endTime"   property="endTime" />
            <result column="two_orderby"   property="orderby" />
            <result column="two_courseId"   property="courseId" />
            <result column="two_coursePubId"   property="coursePubId" />
            <association property="teachplanMedia" javaType="...TeachplanMedia">《《《《
                <id column="teachplanMeidaId"   property="id" /> 
                <result column="mediaFilename"   property="mediaFilename" /> 
                <result column="mediaId"   property="mediaId" />
            </association>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
```

Help a great god, what's the matter that the mapping entity class of my MyBatis mapping file at teachplanMedia is different from the TeachplanMedia I imported? My entity class is Teachplan, and my TeachplanDTO code is as follows.

```
@Data
@ToString
public class TeachplanDto extends Teachplan {

   private   TeachplanMedia teachplanMedia;

    private List<TeachplanDto> teachPlanTreeNodes;
}
```

The entity class I mapped is Teachplan, not TeachplanMedia.

I checked the path, the Mapper file was generated by the generator, and nothing else was changed, but the entity class I finally got was Teachplan.

Comment: Not enough info. If you could share an executable demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) on your GitHub repo or somewhere, I would take a look when I have time. Please minimize the number of columns for simplicity (a few columns for each table should be enough for the demo).